# Compatibility of Apache Spark 2.3.1 and 2.0.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, scala-breeze

I would like to use an application developed with Apache Spark 2.0.0 ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/christinaheinze/loco-lib)) but I only have Spark 2.3.1 installed on my iMac (it seems to be the only one supported by homebrew at the moment). I can successfully compile it with `sbt assembly` but then when I run the first example given [here](http://christinaheinze.github.io/loco-lib/) I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.DenseVector$.canDotD()Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;

Is this a compatibility issue between the two different versions of Scala-breeze used by Spark 2.0.0 and Spark 2.3.1. Is there a way to easily change the code in order to be able to use it with Spark 2.3.1? (I have never used scala  before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is.
You can always manually download required version of Apache Spark (not by homebrew, but by downloading tar.gz archive from official page and just extracting it).